# Data from local storage is getting flushed off every time I refresh the page

Tags: sencha-touch-2, local-storage

m using sencha touch 2 and using local storage in it, 
but the data is getting flushed of as soon as i refresh the page, can u please tell me whats wrong, here is the code for my store and insert delete function

```
Ext.define("OfferDrive.store.CategoryStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    requires: "Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage",
    config: {
        model: "OfferDrive.model.StoreCategories",
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'favorite-category-store'
        }
    }
});
```

here is the code from a view that adds or inserts the record in it

```
            var favCategoriesStore = Ext.getStore('CategoryStore');

            for (var i=0; i< categoryList.config.store.data.items.length; i++)
            { 
                if(categoryList.config.store.data.items[i].data.CheckUrl.indexOf("Golden") != -1){
                    var record = favCategoriesStore.findRecord('Id', categoryList.config.store.data.items[i].data.Id)
                    if (null == record){
                        //insert
                        var newFavorite = Ext.create("OfferDrive.model.StoreCategories", {
                            Id: categoryList.config.store.data.items[i].data.Id,
                            Name: categoryList.config.store.data.items[i].data.Name
                        });
                        favCategoriesStore.add(newFavorite);                                
                    }
                }else{
                    var record = favCategoriesStore.findRecord('Id', categoryList.config.store.data.items[i].data.Id)
                    if (null != record){
                        //remove
                        favCategoriesStore.remove(record);
                    }
                }
            }

            favCategoriesStore.sync();
```

Comment: just checked the developer window of chrome too, store shows there, but with no data :\

Comment: localStorage can store only string data type.

Comment: @KyawTun well it can store int and boolean and other data types too

Comment: The design pattern is to store JSON.stringify string of the record object.  So anything that serialized with JSON will go.

Comment: got it working, used setDirty() method of model and it worked...